# ViewController is showing blank in storyboard

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have copied a ViewController from one project to another. But after that, it is showing blank.

[image]

and I have also tried this:

[image]

any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by:

**Storyboard -> Select ViewController -> Attributes Inspector -> Simulated Size -> Fixed**

Comment: More than 6 years later,I would give this 10 upvotes if I could. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That seems Xcode bug, Quit Xcode and run it again or switch between storyboard it will be normal.

Comment: try switching between multiple storyboards multiple time and also remove those storyboard link outlets as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure after copying viewcontroller your set initial view controller?
[image: Look at this image]

in above image at right middle you can see check box labeld as "**Is initial view controller**" check that box after selecting viewcontroller/navigationcontroller which your want to set first

Comment: not getting your solution...I am not  asking about how to set view controller as initial view controller

Comment: Sorry for that, I just wanted to know that have you set first view controller, because in my case i forgot to set initial view and got same issue